# Knockout checkbox - Push only checked values into array

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have this checkbox control that dynamically populates

```
<!-- ko foreach: AllPens -->
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: IsChecked" />
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
</label>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Assuming the observable array GETs (AllPens)

```
{ code: "001" , name: "Parker"},
{ code: "002" , name: "Sheaffer"},
{ code: "003" , name: "Mont Blanc"}
```

I have to POST back an array of the checked elements -

```
"Pens": [{
    "PenType": "001",
    "Order": false
}, {
    "PenType": "002",
    "Order": true
}]
```

I have a rough idea to store the checked Pen's code and if ischecked in an object - new Pen('001',true)

```
function Pen(type, checked) {
    var self = this;

    self.PenType = ko.observable(type);
    self.IsChecked = ko.observable(false);
}
```

How can I bind checkbox value to Knockout observableArray on an object?

I believe the below should work if i figure out the above.

```
self.Pens= ko.computed(function()
{
    var selectedPens = [];
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.Pen(), function (pen) {
        if(pen.IsChecked())
            selectedPens.push(pen);
    });
    return selectedPens;
});
```

I'm still learning KO. Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to get this working.

Rather than dynamically populating the key value pairs directly to Self.AllPens(), I created a function to load the list of Pens into an Object

```
    function Pen(type,name,checked) {
        var self = this;

        self.PenType= ko.observable(type);
        self.Name = ko.observable(name);
        self.IsChecked = ko.observable(checked || false);            
    }
```

And looped through to check for IsChecked below -

```
        self.Pens= ko.computed(function () {
            var selectedPens = [];
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.AllPens(), function (pen) {
                if (pen.IsChecked()) {
                    selectedPens.push({
                        PenType: pen.penType,
                        Order: pen.IsChecked()
                    });
                }
            });
            return selectedPens ;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You code should be like this

```
self.checkedPens = function(pen) {
    var isChecked = pen.order === "true";
    if (pen.penType !== null && isChecked) {
        self.Pens.push({
            PenType: pen.penType,
            Order: isChecked
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Should I be using `$parent.chosenItems` to check if the the checkbox is checked?

Comment: I think yes but not sure first try to debug your code or try check with console if you getting correct value than you can use.